# How model tracked bifacial PV modules with python?

Tags: python, pvlib

I'm structuring a monitoring system for a photovoltaic plant with pvlib. As the modules are bifacial and are mounted on a solar tracker (2p), I am using pvfactors. I believe I have already resolved the dependencies: pvfactors 1.5.1, pvlib 0.7.0, and shapely reinstalled via conda.

As the modules do not have parameters for the Sandia model, I intend to use the de Soto model.

I plan to run the code automatically once a day with the weather data collected during the period.

I would like to know if anyone has any code developed with pvfactors and single diode models for the modules.

Sure of your attention, thank you in advance!

Ben Possatto

Comment: Fixing: pvlib version is 0.8.0

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can model a single-axis tracked bifacial system using pvlib.tracking.SingleAxisTracker (inherits from a PVSystem instance) to calculate surface_tilt and surface_azimuth, then pass those results to pvfactors_timeseries to get the front and rear irradiance.